# Azure devops yaml pipelines get branches from different repo to use them as a value list in a param

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Scenario:

I have a azure git repo for all my infrastructure code (basically all my yaml files are there and are triggered from there for any other jobs needed).

I want to be able to get all branches from repository `x` and use them as a value list in a parameter.

Basically:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo_x
    type: git
    name: Proj/repo_x

"""
Something should happen here and give me a list of branches from repo_x 
in a variable 'branch_list'
"""

parameters:
  - name: branch
    displayName: Target branch
    type: string
    default: 'main'
    values: [branch_list]
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to get all of the branches from the repository. Are you not merging branches back to trunk? If so, why not?

Comment: Allowing adhoc runs of branches for testing purposes. It's safer to have the branches like this than relying on people to write the correct branch name (especially with our branch naming convention)

Comment: @Nick have you solved your issue? I would like to know how to get list of branch name list as parameter in YAML

Comment: @taipei sadly no, we're switching to jenkins because of the many limitations azure devops has

Answer (score 0):

when we trigger a pipeline, the branch list is already available, this defines in which version the pipeline will run, is this what you want ?
[image]

Comment: Sadly no, these are scripted pipelines that have the pipeline `yaml` files in a different repository from the development code.

What i need is a way to programmatically get all the branches from a different repo inside the pipeline as a variable of type list

Comment: @Nick, with parameter as you requested in your initial question, I dont think is possible. But with variable, it should be possible, but a little bit hardcode, where you can write a script to query AzDO API to get the branches list, and then save it in a variable.